# undefined reference to __glewGenBuffers

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glew

I get this error even though I linked GLEW properly. I don't know why it says  this. GLEW itself works but it isn't linking to VBO related stuff. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post more information please? It would be useful to hear how you're compiling (particually details of how you're linking GLEW), and exactly what the error message is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to \`\_imp\_\_glewInit@0'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710677/undefined-reference-to-imp-glewinit0)

Comment: I linked it by linking the libraries required (the .lib's), adding the directory path to the include, linking the library by using `-lglew32` after linking OpenGL and GLFW (I'm using GLFW), and then defining `GLEW_STATIC` by using `-DGLEW_STATIC`. I'm using MinGW 4.6.2. The error doesn't show up when initializing it, so I'm assuming it's linked. But the error shows up when calling VBO related functions. I'm also compiling this as C++.

Comment: @BrianA.Martinez did you add `glewExperimental=TRUE;` before `glewInit();`